# Fixed divider in the table

Tags: html, html-table, scrollbar, gsp

I'm having some troubles with my tables as I can't seem to fixed the divider as the text increases. It will move the divider by a few pixel as the text gets longer. I will post a few screen shots for you to see.

[image: Screenshot]

After adding some text in:

[image: Screenshot]

It becomes like this.
So is there anyone out there that can help me with this? Btw this is my code

```
 <table border="2" style='overflow:scroll' height=50px >
        <th width=100px nowrap>Username</th>
        <th width=100px nowrap>Email</th>
 </table>
         <div style="height: 200px; overflow: scroll; width: 100%;">   
<table border="2" style='overflow:scroll' height=200px >     
   <g:each in="${result}" >
    <tr>
        <td width=100px nowrap style='overflow:hidden'>${it.username}aaaaaaaa</td>
        <td width=100px nowrap style='overflow:hidden'>${it.email}</td>
    </tr>       
        </g:each>
 </table>
```

I wanted to remove the bottom scroll bar too, but I can't seem to hide it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) To remove bottom scrollbar change overflow:scroll to `overflow-y:scroll` or `overflow:auto`

2) To fix width issue either put width property of TD in style attribute (recommended)

```
style='overflow:hidden; width:100px'
```

OR

set `width='100'` only without word px

Comment: Thanks for replying! I've fixed the issues with scrollbar. However, the issues with the TD still persist. I need to have a fixed width. Because as there are the data with longer text, and its affecting the witdh of the row. So is there any way to fix the width without the text affecting it?

Comment: Add word-wrap: break-word; property to TD style attribute